.NET 8.0 SDK vs runtime compatibility
I'm trying to understand the relationship between the version of the SDK used to build an assembly and the version of the runtime required by that assembly; in terms of compatibility.
Background
The reason for the question is that a build is working locally, on a machine with up-to-date Visual Studio; but the same thing is failing to build on the build server (which is not up to date).
The error can be replicated locally by installing the older SDK and pinning the version using a global.json file. So we want to update the build tools on the build server to solve the build error, but we aren't sure we understand whether doing so will require the machines where the application runs, to have a new version of the runtime.
The places where the application runs definitely have a .NET 8.0 runtime in place; but there doesn't seem to be consistency in the runtime version numbers across those servers.
In our projects, we just put <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework> to say what the target runtime is.
Research
There was an approximately similar question from 5 years ago, but it has zero answers.
How the .NET Runtime and SDK are versioned - .NET explains that the SDK and the runtime are released independently, giving the .NET 5 versions as an example.
The Download .NET 8.0 page lists the different versions of the runtime and the SDKs, and these are grouped under the runtime's version number, which is summarised as follows:

Runtime 8.0.0 is listed with SDK 8.0.100
Runtime 8.0.1 is listed with SDK 8.0.101
Runtime 8.0.2 is listed with SDK 8.0.201 and SDK 8.0.200 and SDK 8.0.102
Runtime 8.0.3 is listed with SDK 8.0.203 and SDK 8.0.202 and SDK 8.0.103
Runtime 8.0.4 is listed with SDK 8.0.204 and SDK 8.0.104
Runtime 8.0.5 is listed with SDK 8.0.300 and SDK 8.0.205 and SDK 8.0.105
Runtime 8.0.6 is listed with SDK 8.0.302 and SDK 8.0.301 and SDK 8.0.206 and SDK 8.0.106
Runtime 8.0.7 is listed with SDK 8.0.303 and SDK 8.0.107
Runtime 8.0.8 is listed with SDK 8.0.400 and SDK 8.0.304 and SDK 8.0.108

This seems to be implying that anything built with those SDK versions will require the associated runtime version to work, because each new runtime version is accompanied by a new version of the SDK for each of the multiples of 100 in the final part (except the 200-series that I'll come back to in a moment).
Each of those 100 groups contains every single sequential number (e.g. you can find all the numbers from 100 to 108 - there are no gaps), even if that means having two entries from the same 100-group against the same runtime, which implies that this is documenting which runtime you need for which SDK.
I'm guessing that each jump of 100 in the final part indicates a new feature/improvement being added, and I'm guessing that the 200-series has died a death for some reason when 8.0.7 came along (because it doesn't appear in 8.0.8 either).
Question
So how can I tell which runtime is required by an assembly, based on the version of the SDK that I'm using to build it (or would anything build with any 8.0 SDK version work on any 8.0 runtime)?
Ideally I'd like the answer to have a reference back to somewhere on a Microsoft page where it actually supports the answer, because I would have thought it would be there somewhere; but I haven't been able to find it.

Check out the Select the .NET version to use doc. The Framework-dependent apps roll-forward section explains the roll-forwarding behavior for the runtime (in short - minor version roll-forward).
The next step is to check what runtime version would be used. One option is to check the YourAppName.runtimeconfig.json which will have something like the following:
"frameworks": [
{
    "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
    "version": "8.0.0"
},
{
    "name": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.App",
    "version": "8.0.0"
}
],

Which (as far as I understand) means that it should work with any installed 8.+ runtime.
I have tested it in Linux docker image by using newer SDK version and earlier runtime one:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0.1 AS base
# ...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0.401  AS build

And it worked just fine, reporting corresponding runtimes/SDK versions (8.0.1 for the application image and 8.0.8/8.0.401 for the build one).
Though there are definitely cases when app picks app the runtime version which is newer - see for example .NET 6 app fails to start because wrong SDK version on server .

Thankyou, this is really useful information. To answer the question, it's just missing the final piece of the puzzle, which is how the *.runtime.json's runtimeOptions:framework:version value is decided. .NET Runtime config options - .NET doesn't explain.
